# How can i Not repeatedly printing previous data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want not to print the previous data repeatedly as below
As i mentioned below just i want to Location array ---> [0.7646998109264953], [0.727837685365675], [0.5799232797025078]
I write the how works my method(entrpoy_calculate)

Any suggestion for similiar to my array ? Or where is my fault i cant find better function from that i wrote

```
except_raintomorrow = categorical_data[:-1]
```

```
for i in avustralya_hava_data[except_raintomorrow].columns:
    
    kolonun_nunique_sayisi = avustralya_hava_data[i].nunique()
    
    print(avustralya_hava_data[i].name)
    for j in range(kolonun_nunique_sayisi):
        t = pd.DataFrame(avustralya_hava_data.loc[avustralya_hava_data[i] == avustralya_hava_data.loc[:,i].unique()[j]][[i, "RainTomorrow"]])
        Entropy = entropy_calculate(t, t["RainTomorrow"].name)
        print(Entropy)
```

```
def entropy_calculate(dataframe, column_name):
    """
    Summary:
        Veri setinin tüm kolonlarının entropsini bulup
        sırasıyla liste icine ekliyor

    Args:
        dataframe (data.Frame): Veri seti
        column_name (str): kolonun adı
    
    Raises :
        Exception :
            Eger object veri tipi dışında bir
            veri tipi girilirse exception fırlatır.
        
    Returns:
        list : kolonların entropileri      
    """
    if dataframe[column_name].dtypes == "O":
        c_data_copy = dataframe[column_name].value_counts()
        
        entropy = 0
        len_of_cdata = len(c_data_copy)
        
        for i in range(len_of_cdata):
            
            p_of_val = (c_data_copy[i] / dataframe.shape[0])
            entropy += -(math.log(p_of_val, 2) * p_of_val)
            
            if i == len(c_data_copy) - 1:
                entropy_list.append(entropy)
    else:
        raise Exception("Sadece kategorik verilerin entropisi hesaplanır.")
        
    return entropy_list

#for i in avustralya_hava_data[categorical_data].columns:
   # entropy_calculate(avustralya_hava_data, avustralya_hava_data[i].name)
```

```
Location
[0.7646998109264953]
[0.7646998109264953, 0.727837685365675]
[0.7646998109264953, 0.727837685365675, 0.5799232797025078]
[0.7646998109264953, 0.727837685365675, 0.5799232797025078, 0.8834118633385486]
[0.7646998109264953, 0.727837685365675, 0.5799232797025078, 0.8834118633385486, 0.6494216690196084]
[0.7646998109264953, 0.727837685365675, 0.5799232797025078, 0.8834118633385486, 0.6494216690196084, 0.8252349197272159]
[0.7646998109264953, 0.727837685365675, 0.5799232797025078, 0.8834118633385486, 0.6494216690196084, 0.8252349197272159, 0.8750844490991014]
```

Comment: Unindent `print(Entropy)` one level.

Comment: To print only the last element in the list on every row you can change `print(Entropy)` to `print(Entropy[-1])`. If you want to print everything on one row, do as @Axe319 said.